p-values based on clustered se with glm
I would like to retrieve the p-values from glm with clustered standard errors. I have used a function to calculate the clustered standard errors and then use these to generate a summary of the model results. When I performed a manual calculation of the p-values that I got from the summary of the model results, the p-values are not similar with the ones I have calculated manually.
I follow three steps to calculate manually the p-values.

Estimate clustered se and store them as a vector.

Calculate the z-value based on the formula:  estimated coefficient / clustered se.

Retrieve the two-sided p-value based on the z-value. I use normal distribution as I have a logistic regression.


Below is the code for my test.
data(mtcars)

cluster <- sample(1:3, 32, replace =TRUE)

mtcars <-cbind(mtcars, cluster)

model <- glm(am ~ wt + hp, data = mtcars, family = binomial(link = "logit"))

# Extract coefficients

coef_estimates <- coef(model)

# function for the clusterred se
get_CL_vcov<-function(model, cluster){
  require(sandwich, quietly = TRUE)
  require(lmtest, quietly = TRUE)
  
  #calculate degree of freedom adjustment
  M <- length(unique(cluster))
  N <- length(cluster)
  K <- model$rank
  dfc <- (M/(M-1))*((N-1)/(N-K))
  
  #calculate the uj's
  uj  <- apply(estfun(model),2, function(x) tapply(x, cluster, sum))
  
  #use sandwich to get the var-covar matrix
  vcovCL <- dfc*sandwich(model, meat=crossprod(uj)/N)
  return(vcovCL)
}

model_vcov <- get_CL_vcov(model, mtcars$cluster)

model_cse <- sqrt(diag(model_vcov))

# z-values for each coefficient
z_values <- coef_estimates / model_cse 

# two-tailed p-values using normal distribution for z-values
p_values <- 2 * pnorm(-abs(z_values))


#### Compare results for no clusterred se, clusterred se (p-values not manually corrected) and clusterred se (p-values manually calculated)
#summary(model_cse)

summary(model)

summary(model, model_cse)

p_values

I am not sure if the problem is with the way how I calculate the clustered standard errors or the p-values. Is there maybe some adjustment that I need to do for my formula or anything I should still consider? The sample I use is with n=32 just to illustrate the problem but I don't think that this is the reason why I have different p-values.

All you need to do is supply the output of glm() to lmtest::coeftest() and supply the VCOV matrix to get the statistics.
lmtest::coeftest(model, vcov = model_vcov)

This produces the tests with the VCOV matrix you computed. You can also use sandwich to compute the VCOV matrix within coeftest():
lmtest::coeftest(model, vcov = sandwich::vcovCL, cluster = ~cluster, type = "HC1")

These produce the same values, which are equal to the p-values you manually computed.
The syntax summary(model, model_cse) is invalid; the second argument to summary() is the dispersion parameter for the GLM, not the standard error estimates.
